# Unable to connect to Force.com after installing IDE

Tags: force.com, ide, install

I have been trying to install the latest Eclipse IDE for Force.com, but kept running into the "Invalid Api version specified on URL error". It's similar to this thread

[Force.com IDE unwilling to create New Project](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42053/force-com-ide-unwilling-to-create-new-project)

But I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't connect to my account when I try to create a new project. It just keeps on saying "unable to fetch Organization detail"

I'm using a developer account that was created 2~3 weeks ago. I was following the install directions through here
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

- Eclipse installed - Version: Kepler Service Release 2
                  Build id: 20140224-0627
- Java installed - ver 7 update 60 (I have ver 8 update 5 installed prior to trying 7/60)

I have also tried to create the Project offline then create classes that way, but get the same error. clicking work online produces the same error... I'm not sure what else to try now.

Side note, I've only used Eclipse when I was in school (3~6 month I think) and that was 10 years ago, so please be patient with me. (I read a couple threads and noticed a bunch of guides that sent my head spinning, unsure what they were referring to most of the time...)

Comment: You Eclipse IDE has been upgraded to version 31 and the organisation to which you trying to create force.com project support version 30 only. So it is an expected issue. You have to either wait for upgrading organization or downgrade the eclipse plugin to v30.0

Comment: oh ok, how would I go about downgrading to v30? I have been looking around but I think I'm searching using the wrong term.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-revert-to-older-versions-of-Force-com-IDE&language=en_US 

In Eclipse we follow the normal Force.com IDE Plugin instructions, except we can choose to not Show only the latest versions of available software.


Help | Install New Software...
Click Add... button to add a new site.
Call it "Force.com IDE (Old)", give it the value of http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ and click OK.
Untick the "Show only the latest versions of available software"
Expand the Force.com IDE node and we'll see that there are the previous versions.

Comment: Thanks guys it works, didn't realize that's what that step meant. Any one of you want to reply using Answer this question just so I can mark it as the answer? Thanks a bunch,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck '*Show only the latest versions of available software*' and install version 30 of the plugin.

adnsandbox.com is mentioned in the help documentation but I would much rather use the standard installation source.

You may need to uninstall version 31 by going to *Help > About > Installation Details*.

Once your org has been updated to version 31 you can uninstall update your plugin to version 31.

Answer (score 3):

You Eclipse IDE has been upgraded to version 31 and the organisation to which you trying to create force.com project support version 30 only. So it is an expected issue. You have to either wait for upgrading organization or downgrade the eclipse plugin to v30.0

Uninstall current plugin and install old plugin from http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/

Answer (score 0):

Update your java version to the latest version (at least 1.8) then restart your computer.
That's what I did.

Good luck